# Minimum Blank pages required in Passport for visiting Turkey, Romania, Spain and Austria on Multiple Entry Schengen Visa

Tags: schengen, turkey, romania, passport-stamps

I am an Indian Passport holder with short term Multiple Entry Schengen Visa.
I intent to Visit Turkey (on basis of e visa), Romania (on basis of multiple entry Schengen visa) then Spain, followed by Austria.

Would travelling to all the aforementioned countries based on 2 blank pages in my passport pose any problem at immigration counters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No problem you will be fine, on Schengen visa page you will be stamped first by Romanian immigration and then later on the same page by Spanish and Austrian authorities.As far as turkey is concerned, you do not  need a separate blank page as turkey stamped  my passport 5 to 6 times on used pages .
On a safe side you have 2 blank pages, you will have no problem in getting in those countries.

Comment: Your view point makes sense is shared by majority of the people!

Answer (score 3):

Technically speaking it is possible, but personally, I would not risk it with two blank pages, considering:

1. At departure from India, you'll get an exit stamp.
2. At arrival in Turkey, you will get an entry stamp.
3. At departure from Turkey, you will get an exit stamp.
4. At arrival in Romania, you'll receive an entry stamp (Romania is not part of Schengen).
5. At departure from Romania, you'll recieve an exit stamp.
6. At arrival in the Schengen area (Spain), you'll receive an entry stamp.
7. Travel between Spain and Austria (and in the Schengen zone) is stamp-free.

Assuming you intend to go back to India, you'll have to have room for the various exit stamps you'll need. At least one for exit from the Schengen zone, and then one for entry into India.

From my travels through Schengen they always stamp the exit next to the entry stamp, and they have never stamped on a non-blank page.

Comment: Have you had space issues though or did you try to ask them to save space and stamp on a non-blank page? That might help here. +1

Comment: what kind of risk we are talking here?

Comment: Does India stamp their own citizens passports? Many/most countries do not.

Comment: @burhan khalid: I guess I will take my chances here. I got your point. I would have to politely convince the immigration officer to be grateful while stamping my passport :).

Comment: @Willeke : yes, Indian authorities stamp upon entry and exit on passport of Indian citizens!

Comment: @Ali Awan : risk of being sent back by immigration authorities !

Comment: @Mts : yes, that is what needs to be done !

Comment: i have obtained schengen visas 15 times from differet consulates.once i traveled first from Montenegro and Croatia and then entered schengen through Slovenia on Italian visa, schengen did not stamp in front of schengen visa. another 1 on Greece multiple visa i entered Romania and bulgaria and then greece, again Greece did not stamp in front of Greece visa.also once i entered Germany even though there was whole empty page Germany place exit stamp on different page. schengen visa from Sweden i entered through Stockholm and exit through Bergen (Norway),Bergen again stamped on different page